# Should I use disabled as a boolean?

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes

I have seen both answers on Stack Overflow.

- In some places, it says disabled is not boolean-based. They say you need to use `Element.removeAttribute("disabled")`.
- I have seen in other places that you use disabled as a boolean. They say simply use `Element.disabled = true` or `Element.disabled = false`.

I have tested it out and both work exactly the same. Is there a speed or optimization advantage to one of these methods? Or is it a matter of preference? Is one a better practice?

Comment: I would guess that there was some compatibility problems between browsers, so there was a need to intoduce different ways of doing the same thing. I personally would prefer the Element.removeAttribute("disabled") due the fact that is clar and easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically its just a matter of preference, but I generally don't use it as boolean because of the actual characteristic it represents, although it may be useful as boolean if you're using it in external hardware as it may be more adaptable to it.

Comment: What do you mean by more adaptable in external hardware?

Comment: Yeah, it requires less power in physical devices as its a simpler decision to make as a 0 or 1, but removeAttr has been seen to have more than just 0 and 1 for some reason.

Comment: Please explain further

Comment: I didn't mean to say power, but the voltage it uses and operates on.

Answer (score 0):

The 'disabled' attribute is a boolean attribute. The default value of 'disabled' is true. So if you use only 'disabled'  then it will act like disabled="true". But when you need false value of it then you should use disabled="false" or just remove the 'disabled' attribute.

For XHTML disabled="disabled"  is the valid.
For HTML5 only 'disabled' is valid and used by W3C on their samples

Comment: I know how to use disabled in Booleans and remove attributes. I need to know which one to use.

Comment: Check it out https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-disabledformelements-disabled.There is no specification but disabled="true" is not used by WC